# In which format should we save graphics (png,pdf,....) in a document class report?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, size

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.5]{graph1}
\caption{hhhhh}
\end{figure}
```

I have no control over the figure position. It is shifted to the right and the caption is very separated from the graph.

I used GIMP. I took a snapshot of the graph, then, into GIMP > I did rectangular selection, then > export as > png.

Is this the right way to include graphics?

Comment: You should really read an introduction. The figure is either shifted to the side, because it is centered. Or there is some white background you do not notice. *How* you create the graphic doesn't matter at all.

Comment: The snippet you indicated is correct, I think it is your original image that is not centered.

Comment: Wrap an `\fbox{...} ` around `\includegraphics{...} ` then you can see what latex thinks are the dimensions of the image. BTW, using width instead of scale is often more useful.

Comment: including a screenshot as a png bitmap is of course a general method that works to include any kind of thing, but it's only a last resort if nothing else is available. You didn't say what file type you gave to to gimp, most likely latex could have included the original file.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: This was resolved by taking a snapshot, then pasting it in GIMP, then click "Edit" and choose "copy", then click" Edit " again and choose "paste as" a new image. Then export it as png. This method is useful for removing the white background that is causing the problem.